# Scala's way to find if the input is a member of a set

Tags: scala

The problem is simple.  In Java terms, the function is given a string; if the string is null, return false; otherwise return whether the UPPERCASE of the string is in some fixed set.  So, something like this:

```
static boolean inSet(String s) {
   return (s != null) && StaticSet.contains(s.toUpperCase());
}
```

I would like to use that as example of how things are more readable in Scala.  Here's what I have

```
object MisspelledColour {
   val StaticSet = Set("RED", "BLEW", "GRENE")
   def inSet(s : Option[String]): Boolean = {
       s map { StaticSet contains _.toUpperCase  } getOrElse false
   }
   def main(args: Array[String]) {
      println(inSet(None));
      println(inSet(Some("blew")));
      println(inSet(Some("blue")));
   }
}
```

What I am looking for is something more *aesthetically* pleasing than `s map { StaticSet contains _.toUpperCase  } getOrElse false`, something that better demonstrates Scala's advantages.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

My variant:

```
def inSet(op:Option[String]) = op.map(_.toUpperCase).exists(StaticSet)
```

Comment: Haha.  Perfect.  I totally forget the obviously true fact that a Set is a predicate (and I never knew about exists(), but I suppose it works on every collection).

Comment: Or `StaticSet.contains` if you want to be more explicit.

Comment: @AlexeyRomanov -- we are getting into the realm of taste, but I like the way "exists(Set)" suggests, somewhat misleadingly, "exists in Set".

Answer (score 1):

How about this:

```
scala> val StaticSet = Set("RED", "BLEW", "GRENE")
StaticSet: scala.collection.immutable.Set[String] = Set(RED, BLEW, GRENE)

scala> def inSet(s: Option[String]): Boolean = s.fold(false)(x => StaticSet(x.toUpperCase))
inSet: (s: Option[String])Boolean

scala> inSet(None)
res0: Boolean = false

scala> inSet(Some("blew"))
res1: Boolean = true
```

Or this:

```
scala> def inSet(s: Option[String]): Boolean = s.exists(x => StaticSet(x.toUpperCase))
inSet: (s: Option[String])Boolean

scala> inSet(None)
res2: Boolean = false

scala> inSet(Some("blew"))
res3: Boolean = true
```